# Magento2 - Lazy loading require-js top level modules per page content

Tags: magento2

Taking Luma theme on M2.2 (current develop tip), and running in production mode, loading the homepage why am I seeing jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js being loaded when it's not used on the homepage? Im seeing over 500KB of Javascript being pulled on a homepage load which is very concerning.

This seem really non idiomatic use of require-js.

Comment: It almost seems as if we eagerly load everything, understandable for an SPA but insane for public facing non-SPA apps regardless of client-side caching directives the javascript still need to be interpreted

Comment: Seems Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap depends on Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker and so on.. it isn't doing any element checking to see if such a kitchen sink will ever be used, disappointing